# How to access pod externally, i.e. bind localhost:8888 to cluster IP

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service running on localhost:8888 and trying to bind that to cluster's public IP so that I can open it up from my web browser. I created another service using the following yaml file:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "example-service"
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [{
      "port": 8888,
      "targetPort": 8888
    }],
    "selector": {
      "app": "example"
    },
    "type": "LoadBalancer"
  }
}
```

Then I do `kubectl describe services example-service`:

```
Name:           example-service
Namespace:      spark-cluster
Labels:         <none>
Selector:       app=example
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         10.3.0.66
LoadBalancer Ingress:   a123b456c789.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:           <unset> 8888/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 32767/TCP
Endpoints:      <none>
Session Affinity:   None
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  14s       14s     1   {service-controller }           Normal      CreatingLoadBalancer    Creating load balancer
  11s       11s     1   {service-controller }           Normal      CreatedLoadBalancer Created load balancer
```

When I open up `a123b456c789.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8888` in my web browser, it doesn't load. What are the correct steps to access my pod externally?

Answer (score 0):

With your setup the application is available on ip adress of one of your node on port 32767 ( NodePort parameter ) if you want to give a NodePort yourself you need to change the code like this :

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "example-service"
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [{
      "port": 8888,
      "targetPort": 8888
      "nodePort": 8888

    }],
    "selector": {
      "app": "example"
    },
    "type": "LoadBalancer"
  }
}
```

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport

Comment: note: if you want to use node ports outside of the default port range (30000-32767), you have to additionally allow a new range with the `--service-node-port-range` option of the api server, see http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/